# GWT: Some screens are too wide in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, cross-browser, compatibility

We have been using GWT for our product, We are finding difficulty resolving browser compatibility issues.  Firefox displays screens properly, but specifically, some screens are too much wide, spreads across the whole chrome browser. Why so in chrome?
We tried removing some components, like some grids. thought it was responsible for these things. Nothing worked. Did Anyone face the same issue?

Comment: Are you using some kind of Widget library (bootstrap, domino, GMD, ....) or just the plain GWT widgets or something else ?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?